# Is there a way to calculate distance between two coordinates ON TERRAIN and not as the crow flies?

Tags: javascript, openstreetmap, gpx

I am looking for a way to find the distance between two coordinates that have elevation data as well, but I want the solution to take under account the TERRAIN between the two points i.e the shortest way between them on the ground and not "as the crow flies".

I have found and used the Haversine formula for the distance "in the air" but obviously it will not yield the real distance that a man would walk on the ground as in between the two points there might be a slope that goes up and / or down. The larger the distance between the points the bigger the error margin.

I have sampled a real .gpx file and converted its data into JSON format. it looks like this:

```
let jsonSample = [{
    "lat": "57.107297", // 0
    "lon": "-5.334734",
    "ele": "957.00"
  }, // distance between 0 and 1 =>  169.1849929515954 m (as the crow flies) elevation difference: 50.210000000000036
  {
    "lat": "57.106590", // 1
    "lon": "-5.332253",
    "ele": "1007.21"
  }, // distance between 1 and 2 => 162.49601252670058  m (as the crow flies) elevation difference: 23.789999999999964
  {
    "lat": "57.105537", // 2 (summit)
    "lon": "-5.330387",
    "ele": "1031.00"
  }, // distance between 2 and 3 =>  32.45395539826568 m (as the crow flies) elevation difference: -13
  {
    "lat": "57.105284", // 3
    "lon": "-5.330119",
    "ele": "1018.00"
  }];
```

Real distances should be longer than the ones calculated with Haversine formula. But how do I calculate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Googling "haversine formula elevation" found me [this Math.SE question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2075092/haversine-formula-that-includes-an-altitude-parameter).

Heeding the comments, **so long as the distances you're measuring aren't too far apart**, using the Pythagorean Theorem, you can add the elevation deltas in.

> I'd use Pythagoras: let d the Haversine distance and dh the difference in altitudes, `D=sqrt(d**2+dh**2)`.

Something like

```
function haversineWithAltitude(lat1, lon1, alt1, lat2, lon2, alt2) {
    const groundDistanceInMeters = haversine(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2);
    const elevationDifferenceMeters = Math.abs(alt1 - alt2);
    return Math.sqrt(groundDistanceInMeters * groundDistanceInMeters + elevationDifferenceInMeters * elevationDifferenceInMeters);
}
```

should thus work – but as said, this will inevitably become more inaccurate if the length between the points is very long. (At that point, I'd, not being a mathematician and not knowing better, segment the long leg and calculate each distance piecewise.)

Comment: Thanks, yes I was thinking about that but the problem as I said is that the longer the distance sample the bigger the error margin is especially if from one coordinate to the other there's a bit of terrain that looks like a parabola for example if you take this one - https://images.app.goo.gl/CNQV9pY7bjj45KRX6 imagine that the 2 coordinates have the same elevation (5) the Pythagorean Theorem will not work here... Also, Tobler's hiking function will yield better results given the slope but it won't work in a parabola situation either...

Comment: Well, if your trail hasn't been sampled at a rate that would capture the target moving through a parabola of a valley, there's no way you can just guess there is one between two points. If you do have enough samples, though, i.e. essentially you're segmenting the valley into polylines, this should be accurate enough.

Comment: Also, Tobler's function seems to be about _speed_, not distance, as you were asking. (Though it's an interesting formula, I didn't know about it, thanks!)

Comment: There is a way as the .gpx is generated either on a map (like openStreetMap) or really on the terrain with a time stamp. Thus with Tobler, if I have real data (registered on terrain) I can estimate via the speed and the slope - the distance (not easy but doable) but I want a universal tool that will register the real distance when I create a .gpx "on the map" at the planning phase prior to the trek. I couldn't find an API that will "snap" the distance between the two coordinates to the terrain features (maybe by breaking effectively the segment into smaller bits and passing the trace through)

Comment: Right – for either use case, you'd need a terrain elevation dataset or API too.

Comment: Yes, then maybe "carpet bomb" the space between two coordinates with elevation values then try and use a FEM formula on it... (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_element_method) Thanks for the direction! ;-)